# How to factory reset iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am not able to factory restore my iphone5.
I tried every possible way to reset the phone.
It is asking for environmental protection agency log in and password.
I want to erase everything from that phone.

Comment: Is this your iPhone or is it owned by the EPA?  It might still be managed by an MDM system so it will not let you restore it.

Comment: At which point expects your iPhone the EPA log in and password?

Comment: If this is your phone and not owned/managed by the EPA, you'd still need to edit your question (there's an _edit_ link below it) to explain what you've already tried. Saying _I tried every possible way to reset the phone_ doesn't help us to help you - otherwise we may end up giving you suggestions you've already tried! It would also be helpful to know what version of iOS you're running.